# How do you insert multiple rows to datagridview on C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

```
private void btn_insert_item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(textBox9.Text != "" & textBox10.Text != "" & textBox11.Text != "")
            {
                DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add item #" + textBox11.Text + "?",
                    "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert " +
                        "into table_a " +
                        "(order_date, " +
                        "order_no, " +
                        "item_name, " +
                        "item_no) " +
                        "values( " +
                        "sysdate, " +
                        "'" + textBox9.Text + "', " +
                        "'" + textBox10.Text + "', " +
                        "'" + textBox11.Text + "', " +
                        )", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                        dt.Load(dr);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        dr.Close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("item has been added.");
                    }
                }

                if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No change has been made.");
                    button1_Click(sender, e);
                }
            }
    }
```

This is code I use to insert single item # on table_a.
textBox 9 = order_date, textBox10 = order_no and textBox11 = item_no.
if I have textBox12 for item_no too then how do I insert multiple row with item_no on dataGridView? If I put item_no 1 on textBox11 and 10 on textBox12, it should insert 10 rows with same information but item_no from 1 to 10.

Help Please.

Comment: First, stop creating SQL like that.  Use SQL Parameters always.  Then since you are binding to a datasource, add rows to the datasource.  If you take the time to set up an adapter, it will do the updates for you

Comment: How do I do that? :( Could you give an example code?  This is sample code but on real table, it is about 40 columns long and I have to fill in about 30 of them in order to insert one row. I get values from 3 textBoxes and rest of them(27 columns+) are manual static value I put on sql query. I can't even use insert option on datagridview and copy/paste previous row because actual program I made only shows important 10 rows that users need to see and rest of columns are on database table but not on datagridview table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a loop with textBox12.text as the counter

For example:

```
for(int x=1;x<textBox12.text;x++)
{
  //Your code.....
}
```